# Rendering to Google Drive?

Tags: rendering, network

I have a blend that's 493 frames long. 
I have 2 pc's. A desktop and a laptop. I usually bring the laptop to work.*
I looking for a way to render the same blend on both the desktop and the laptop and exporting the frames to a shared folder. 
Since my laptop is going to travel from my workplace to my home and back I think the best way would be using Google Drive to sync the folders.

Google Drive syncs in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\Google Drive.

How can I render to that folder on both my laptop and pc regardless of the user name? Can I use environment variables when rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not use environment variables in the *Output File* field, because it doesn't support drivers (and key-framing also).

You would have to write a python script that would change this field every time you open the file (with *Run Python Scripts* enabled in *Preferences*). In the script you can for sure use [python environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907053/4342203):

```
import bpy
import os

user = os.environ['USERNAME']
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\GoogleDrive\\file_name"
```

---

The best thing to do is to put the .blend file also in the Google Drive folder and use relative paths just like: `//rendered\file_name`(this saves to folder "rendered" next to the .blend file).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea of how complicated would that python script be?

I'm not going to do this for this project since I'm outputting the frames to Multi Layer EXR and each frame is 36mb. I don't have enough space on my Google drive. I'm going to have to sync the rendered frames manually